# Swift 3 - AWS iOS 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION' Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, swift3, ios10

After converting over to Swift 3, my AWS iOS App now crashes when being run.

[image: The Error]

[image: The Calling Function]

Has anyone seen anything similar after converting over to Swift 3?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Its crashing because you are doing a few things here:

1. trying to return a method call (which I don't think is possible - but I've never tried it)
2. `application: didFinishLaunching` should only ever return true because it's a boolean function as the name suggests. So the return value should be true. If you'd like to override `application: didFinishLaunching` you can declare that later in your `AppDelegate`

So here's what you can do... Try deleting the method and slowly type it back until Xcode auto-completes it for you. That will allow you to see what has been depreciated, or what other methods might be useful, also if you haven't yet hit Command + Shift + K to run a clean on your project. Xcode 8 and Swift 3 might have altered a few more things you aren't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

launchOptions is an optional parameter. Doing a forced unwrap with the ! will crash if the value is nil, which it usually is.